# Indentation - numbering with dots

Tags: enumerate

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
\item Stuff stuff
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, the end result is enumeration without dots. It's just 1 2 3, but I want 1. 2. 3.

How do I achieve so?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]` (Isuppose you load `enumitem`?), or better,  `[label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries]` if you do not want the cross references to be in boldface.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, sorry, I edited the post. And not sure what you mean. I am already using what you mentioned.

Comment: With the suggestion of very nice user Bernard `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
\item Stuff stuff
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`. Try it.

Comment: You forgot the dot after `\arabic*` (and I forgot it too, due to a typo, but it's fixed now).

Comment: Thanks, it's working!

Comment: @Bernard I have tried and it works :-(....Should I remove my comment? No problem for me.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I don't think it's necessary. The code in your comment is more complete than my simple sketch, and it may be helpful for some  users.

Answer (score 2):

As per suggestions in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
    \item Stuff stuff 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the period be in bold also?